# way to make all pages with certain tags public?

Tags: pages, publish

I want a way to make all pages with certain tags public.

I don't care if a solution is programatic or via GUI (though I prefer programatic), I just want to be able to make all pages with a certain tag public with just one "click-of-the-button" so to speak.

EDIT:

Oops. I thought pages could have tags just like posts. My intention is to make a bunch of static pages, show them to someone to approve them, and if they approve of the pages, then make them public all at once for the world to see. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by public?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Pages - i.e. *static pages* - don't *have* tags, and by default, *all content* is publicly accessible.

Comment: I am a little confused myself. But I provided an answer based on what I think you're asking and if I am not correct, based on further information I will revise and help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you're asking, so I'm going to stake a wild stab in the dark until you can provide more information provided I don't tell you exactly what you wanted to know. If by public you mean; pages with a certain tag lets say for this example the tag is 'public' and pages that only registered and logged in users can access aren't tagged with public.

The simple answer would be in your post loop you would get a list of post tags assigned to the post using the function [wp_get_post_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags) and then check to see if the public tag exists, if it doesn't show an error message telling the user the post is not accessible or perhaps even redirect the user using the [wp_redirec](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)t function.